# Use localstorageProvider and localstorageProxy in extjs4

Tags: extjs, local-storage, extjs4.2

i try to use a combination of Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider and Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage anyone know a way to do that?

In my app (is use extjs 4.2) i initialize the localStorageProvider in this way:

```
var storageProvider = new Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider( {prefix: 'sample'});
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(storageProvider);
```

With this configuration if i use stateful component all is save and reload. 
The problem is came out when I had to introduce in my app a TabPanel with a dynamic set Tab dependent on the user's local session. 
The tabs contain a set of information that I'm going to save in a LocalStorage proxy dataStore, but when I close the tabpanel the datastore is deleted, as if it were a memoryproxy datastore.

There is a way to transfer the datatstore in a state manage by the Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider?

Any kind of help is usefull.

[EDIT]: This is my code for localstorageStore.

```
Ext.define('Book', {
     fields: ['id', 'name', 'layout'],
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
});

var layoutStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: "Book",
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : 'sample'+'_books'
    }
});
```

For add element in my store, i use:

```
store.add(newElement); 
store.synch();
```

For edit element for example only a field, in the store:

```
var record = store.getAt(index);
record.data.layout = encodeValue;
store.insert(index, record);
```

and for remove element i use

```
store.remove(record);
store.sync();
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your localstorage store? It sounds like maybe it's not configured correctly. I use localstorage stores all the time and they persist data to localstorage as expected.